# analyzing time series in the frequency domain

Tags: matlab, spectral

I am attempting to analyse a time series with spectral analysis. I am trying to detect any periodicities in my data, which is composed of hourly measurements recorded for one week (24 * 7 = 168 measurements), I aim to show the diurnal component of the temperature variation. So far I have (for example):

```
clear all
StartDate = '2011-07-01 00:00';
EndDate = '2011-07-07 23:00';
DateTime=datestr(datenum(StartDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum(EndDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'),...
    'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DateTime=cellstr(DateTime);
DecDay = datenum(DateTime)-datenum(2011,0,0);
t = 0:25/length(DecDay):(25-0.1488);
x = sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);
y = x + 2*randn(size(t));
Y = fft(y,length(y));
```

Where would I go from here? any advice would be much appreciated.

Altered:

```
clear all
    StartDate = '2011-07-01 00:00';
    EndDate = '2011-07-07 23:00';
    DateTime=datestr(datenum(StartDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
        datenum(EndDate,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'),...
        'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
    DateTime=cellstr(DateTime);
    DecDay = datenum(DateTime)-datenum(2011,0,0);
 x = cos((2*pi)/12*DecDay)+randn(size(DecDay));
 % if you have the signal processing toolbox
 [Pxx,F] = periodogram(x,rectwin(length(x)),length(x),1);
 plot(F,10*log10(Pxx)); xlabel('Cycles/hour');
 ylabel('dB/(Cycles/hour');
```

Can anyone suggest how I would convert the x axis to hours instead of cycles per hour? I have tried

```
plot(1./F,10*log10(Pxx)); xlabel('hours');
```

but this messes up the peridogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier to start off with MATLAB's [periodogram](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/signal/ref/periodogram.html) function, rather than trying to use the FFT directly. This takes care of windowing the data for you and various other implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. From my altered example, how would I alter the scaling of the x axis?

Comment: You just need to set the `fs` parameter correctly when you call `periodogram`. If you sample once per hour then `fs = 1/3600`.